# I try to make chart graph component, library . for web and desktop. what language most common?

Tags: web, graph

I try to make chart graph component, library . for web and desktop. what language most common?

I try make very cheap chart, graph component. I worked for 3D engine programmer.

I always use C++ and my own library.

I want to make cheap library component for desktop application and web service.

1. which language is common for desktop developing?
2. what language and platform most use for web page chart?I hope there is no download at all. difficulty is not matter at all for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've just completed a 3D chart library for the desktop, mobile and the web.  I used Java for the desktop, wrote a native Android application (it's a Java-like platform, different API but same programming language), and Javascript (actually Dart compiled to Javascript) for the web.  I didn't do a native iOS version.  Those were my choices, I think it worked out well.  Your mileage may vary.